# Firebase phone auth not working in when signing apk

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-authentication

Before update my app to playstore phone auth works good, but after i update my app stop working. I know i need the sha-1 from the play console in my settings in firebase, i already update this, but still not works in the current play store app.
I download again the google-services.json with the modifications and it works again locally , but when i upload the app, the sha-1 in the play console, change.....Again!! And stop working. 
Looks like a paradigma, because when i change the google-services.json works, but i need to update the app in the play console, but i know when i update again the app, the sha-1 change again, and it turns into an infinite loop.

Comment: How did you generate SHA-1?

Comment: keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android......Using this command,  in the path i use the path of my keystore.jks. If i sign into my firebase account inside android studio, it reads automatically my sha-1 and add to the console, but when i update my app in playstore stops working.